# Alert Component does not show after triggering the same Error twice

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently working on a Website using **Nuxt.js (Vue.js)** and I am having trouble with my custom Alert Component.

I created a contact-form on my website that triggers a custom notification when the user enters wrong data or does not enter all required data. However, if the same error gets triggered twice (e.g. wrong phone number). The alert does not show a second time.

I have now tried to fix this for two days and ChatGPT can't help me either here. So I really hope that one of you knows why this might be happening.

My **custom WarningAlert** component:

```
    <!-- WarningAlert.vue -->
<template>
    <div v-if="show" class="overlay">
      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="alert-icon">
            <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_bell-53"></i>
          </div>
          <strong>{{ strongText }}</strong> {{ message }}
          <button v-if="dismissible" type="button" class="close" @click="hideOverlay" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">
              <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_simple-remove"></i>
            </span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    props: {
      message: String,
      type: String,
      strongText: String,
      dismissible: Boolean,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        show: false,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      hideOverlay() {
        this.show = false;
      },
      showWarningAlert(message) {
        // Show the warning alert with the provided message
        this.message = message;
        this.show = true;
  
        // Hide the warning alert after 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.hideOverlay();
        }, 5000);
      },
      hideWarningAlert() {
        // Dismiss the warning alert
        this.show = false;
        this.message = '';
      },
    },
    watch: {
      message() {
        // sets show true, after an update
        this.show = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          // delayed hiding 5000 Millisekunden (5 Seconds)
          this.hideOverlay();
        }, 5000);
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.showWarningAlert(this.message);
    },
  };
  </script>
  
  <style scoped>
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .alert {
    width: 70%;
  }
  </style>
```

Here is the **contact form and the imported component**:

```
 <!-- Alert component -->
        <WarningAlert v-if="showWarningAlert" :message="warningMessage" :type="'warning'" :strongText="'Warning!'"
          :dismissible="true" @dismiss="dismissWarningAlert"></WarningAlert>
    
<!-- Contact Form -->
        <div class="main">
          <div class="contact-content">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 ml-auto mr-auto">
                  <h2 class="title">Senden Sie uns eine Nachricht</h2>
                  <p class="description">Wir stehen Ihnen gerne zur Verfügung. Wir werden Ihnen innerhalb eines Werktages
                    antworten.
                    <br>
                    <br>
                  </p>
                  <form role="form" id="contact-form" @submit.prevent="submitForm" method="post">
                    <label>Ihr Name</label>
                    <fg-input required placeholder="Name..." v-model="form.firstName"
                      addon-left-icon="now-ui-icons users_circle-08"></fg-input>
    
                    <label>Email Adresse</label>
                    <fg-input required placeholder="Email..." v-model="form.email"
                      addon-left-icon="now-ui-icons users_circle-08" title="Please enter a valid email address"></fg-input>
    
                    <label>Telefon</label>
                    <fg-input required placeholder="Telefonnummer..." v-model="form.phone"
                      addon-left-icon="now-ui-icons tech_mobile"></fg-input>
    
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Ihre Nachricht</label>
                      <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placehiolder="Nachricht..." v-model="form.message" rows="6"></textarea>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="submit text-center">
                      <button class="btn btn-success btn-rounded" type="submit" round>Senden</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

And finally the **CSS of my submitForm() method**, where the error probably lies (as the notification gets triggered here).

```
methods: {
    async submitForm() {
      // Initialisation
      this.showWarningAlert = false;
      this.warningMessage = '';

      // Check if all relevant fields filled out
      if (!this.form.firstName || !this.form.email || !this.form.phone) {
        this.showWarningAlert = true;
        this.warningMessage = 'Please fill out all required fields (Name, Email, Phone).';
        return;
      }

      const emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
      if (!this.form.email.match(emailRegex)) {
        this.showWarningAlert = true;
        this.warningMessage = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
        return;
      }

      const phoneRegex = /^(\+\d{1,3})?\d{1,14}$/;
      if (!this.form.phone.match(phoneRegex)) {
        this.showWarningAlert = true;
        this.warningMessage = 'Please enter a valid phone number.';
        return;
      }

      // Send formulas if everything is validated
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3005/send-email', this.form);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('Email sent successfully');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending email:', error);
        // Show warning if error
        this.showWarningAlert = true;
        this.warningMessage = 'Something went wrong. Please contact us via email.';
      } finally {
        // Reset Warning properties before leaving the method
        this.showWarningAlert = false;
        this.warningMessage = '';
      }
    },
    dismissWarningAlert() {
      // Dismiss the warning alert
      this.showWarningAlert = false;
      this.warningMessage = '';
    }
  },
```

Comment: Could be something to do with your `showWarningAlert`. Have you console logged its value throughout testing the feature to narrow down the logical error?

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I have console logged it and it stays true. However, I did not manage to turn it back to 'false'. This is why I also tried the initialisation at the beginning of the submitForm() message.

Comment: Notice that in your custom component you define `showWarningAlert` as a method but when you actually use it you treat it as a boolean variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you could save yourself some headaches by simply moving a few things around in your code.

##### Toggle State

The first thing that stands out to me is that you're storing the toggle state for your alert in two separate places - in the alert component itself (as `this.show`) and also in the submitForm method for your form (as `this.showWarningAlert`). Arguably, the best place to store the variable that represents the visibility state of your alert toggle is in the parent component, in this case the component that also contains your form. I'd recommend passing this variable through to the alert component via a prop and use the prop value in the v-if inside your alert component.

Is `this.showWarningAlert` initialized in the parent context? If it is then great, you can pass `this.showWarningAlert` in to the child (alert) component via props. Then if you want to change the toggle state, you can emit from the child component (see below) up to the parent component which holds the toggle state in a variable (i.e. `this.showWarningAlert`)

##### No emits

Your alert component also appears to be missing an emit called 'dismiss', which according to your code is supposed to trigger your dismissWarningAlert method. I'd move all the methods that toggle the alert visibility up to the parent component (in the same context where the toggle state `this.showWarningAlert` is stored) and if you want to automatically time-out the visibility of your alert, you can set a watch on the value of the visibility prop coming in to the alert and set a setTimeout method whenever the value changes to `true`.

##### Also...

I also noticed that you are using mixed quotes when passing strings as props to your alert component. You can drop the `:` on the `type` and `strongText` attributes of your alert component, as well as the single quotes inside the double quotes... (i.e. `type="warning" strongText="Warning!"`) It will make those attributes look a little cleaner and you won't be squinting to double-check you've got the right type of quotation in the right place ;)

#### I hope some or all of the above helped in some way!